# How would I draw this using CGContext

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

I want to draw this in my view to draw this line, I have everything I need to make a basic line, but am just not good at drawing, I did in fact try to do this, but just cannot get it to work correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should draw a sine curve like the one you describe, assuming currentBounds is the bounding rectangle for your area to draw within:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds) - currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds) - currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds) - currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds), CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds) + currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds) + currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, currentBounds.size.width - currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds) + currentBounds.size.width / 5.0f, currentBounds.size.width, CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds));
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)? If you know where the two control points are located, use

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(context, ...); // Cubic Bézier curve
```

or

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, ...); // Quadratic Bézier curve
```

to insert the curve, then use

```
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

to stroke the curve.

Comment: @Jaba: You don't even provide the numbers (widths, heights, the position of the 3 highlighted points), how can anyone provide the actual points.